# Find words between 2 not includes words in the results with regex

Tags: java, regex

I tried to find the solution but could not.

A regex which selects all words of more than 3 characters between the words "(Dd)og(s)" and "(Cc)at(s)". Using a Regex. the words "(Dd)og(s)" and "(Cc)at(s)" shall not be included in the result in Java.
I found:

```
(?<=(^?\b[Dd]ogs?\b\s?|^?\b[Cc]ats?\b\s?)).*(\b[a-zA-Z']{4,}\b)*(?=(\b[Dd]ogs?\b\s|\b[Cc]ats?\b\s))
```

It works but it gives words of 3 and less characters.

Comment: This is the result that I get: 

Dogs **are nice animals.** Cats are not. 
My cat **ate a mice. My** dog once ate a fry. 
My dog **once ate a fry. My** cat ate a mice. 
The catalog of the best dogs is around here somewhere.

It should be only words with more than 3 characters.

Comment: I found this:
`(?i)((?<=(^?dogs? |^?\s?cats? ))(.*?)(?=(dogs?|cats?)))`
Dogs **are nice animals.** Cats are not.
My cat **ate a mice. My** dog once ate a fry.
My dog **once ate a fry. My** cat ate a mice. 

The catalog of the best dogs is around here somewhere.
Now I need to get only the 4 plus characters long words.

Answer (score 0):

Since in the pattern in the comments `(?i)((?<=(^?dogs? |^?\s?cats? ))(.*?)(?=(dogs?|cats?)))` you use a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to match either cat or dog and from that you need to get only the 4 plus characters long words, you might make use of `\G` which asserts the end of the previous match.

For example:

```
(?:\b(?:dog|cat)s?|\G)\s+(?:((?!(?:dog|cat)s?\b)\w{3,})|\S+)(?=.*?\s+(?:dog|cat)s?\b)
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?:\\b(?:dog|cat)s?|\\G)\\s+(?:((?!(?:dog|cat)s?\\b)\\w{3,})|\\S+)(?=.*?\\s+(?:dog|cat)s?\\b)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhSVqV/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OeA4F8)

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\b(?:dog|cat)s?` Word boundary, match either dog or cat with an optional s
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(` Capturing group

    - `(?!(?:dog|cat)s?\b)\w{3,}` Negative lookahead to check what follows is not dog or cat with an optional s. If that is the case, then match 3+ times a word char
  - `)` Close capturing group
  - `|` Or
  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars since we can not match `\w{3,}`
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(?=.*?\s+(?:dog|cat)s?\b)` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is either dog or cat with an optional s